# Why receiving a zip file from kuzzle with the js sdk does not work?

Tags: node.js, websocket, kuzzle

I want to send a zip from my kuzzle backend so i wrote that in my backend:

```
// Generate zip file
    const zip = new JSZip()
    zip.file(filename, zipData)
    const finalZipFile = await zip.generateAsync({
      type:"nodebuffer",
      compression: "DEFLATE",
      compressionOptions: {
        level: 6
      }
    })
req.response.configure({
      // Tell Kuzzle that this result will contain a raw payload
      format: 'raw', 
      headers: {
        // Set HTTP response headers
        'Content-Length': finalZipFile.length.toString(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="${filenameBase + ".zip"}"`,
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      }
    });
    return finalZipFile;
```

But when i make a request using the nodejs sdk:

```
const result = await kuzzle.query({
      controller: "hahaha",
      action: "hahaha"
    })
    console.log(result)
```

i get an error message:

```
/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/kuzzle-sdk/src/KuzzleError.js:32
        super(apiError.message);
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
    at new KuzzleError (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/kuzzle-sdk/src/KuzzleError.js:32:24)
    at WebSocket.client.onmessage (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/kuzzle-sdk/src/protocols/WebSocket.js:159:35)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1137:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:528:14)
    at Receiver.getData (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:446:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:148:22)
    at Receiver._write (/Users/doriancruveiller/Desktop/kuzzle-plugin-test/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:83:10)
```

But the weird thing is that it works just fine if i do the same request with wscat. Maybe a bug in the nodeJS sdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you just hit the [server.maxRequestSize](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle/blob/master/.kuzzlerc.sample#L369) limit of the network layer.

You should increase this limit to send bigger files to Kuzzle.

Also, consider using [S3 based storage](https://github.com/kuzzleio/kuzzle-plugin-s3) with [Pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)instead of storing file directly on Kuzzle because this will not works properly in a cluster environment.

Comment: i tried to put server.maxRequestSize to 3GB, i see it in app.config but it still does not work as i am getting the same error message

Comment: I think I just figured your issue, since the response is a raw zip file, it cannot be parsed by the SDK. You need to expose your API action through HTTP, then if you are in a browser then just generate the corresponding HTTP link and if you are in Node.js then use an HTTP lib to download it